# the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered

Tags: vb.net

I am creating an application using vb.net and access 2007. My OS is in 64bit, windows 7. I already change my TargetFlatform in to x86. But when I run the program error occured "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine". I tried to search with google for a solution but no luck.

any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you must install Access Database Engine, see the following link

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

Regards.

Comment: hi carmelo,  I already tried to install AccessDatabaseEngine.exe and still the same error. When I try another one AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe it says "you cannot install the 64-bit version of microsoft access database engine 2010 because you have 32-bit office products ..."

Comment: I've found some advise to change the "any cpu" into "x86" but when I changed it the error "D:\system development\SolveIT Food Service\SolveIT Food Service\bin\data\food_service.accdb" is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which files resides. Here is my data connection "(dataCon = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=D:\system_development\SolveIT Food Service\SolveIT Food Service\bin\data\food_service.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password = 'solveitfs'")"

Answer (score 0):

There is a **problem** with **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12** when **AccessDatabaseEngine** x86 or x64 ***2010*** is installed.

I have long attempted to use the SSMS (2005-2008-2008R2-2012) Export Wizards to export large tables onto Excel and I needed the AccessDatabaseEngine installed to be able to do that.

However, regardless of the MS Office version (2010, x86 or x64, or whatever it is), the 2010 version of AccessDatabaseEngine will not work towards registering the provider.

The solution is to download and install the previous one which is none other than the **2007 x86** one.
This one will work even if Office or SQL Server or VS are x64.

Download it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Now, any other propagated issues revolving around the notorious failure to register "the provider" on the local machine for the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12 should be resolved by the above.

Feel free to paste me your experiences on this matter.